# Blender crash after closing area from python script

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm working on a contextual script for 3D_VIEW that shows a popup panel with different properties/buttons/operators.
One of the buttons calls the operator to close the area in which the script was called.
The area is closed using `bpy.ops.screen.area_close()`.

Unfortunately by doing this I have errors relating to some properties of the area displayed in the panel, I imagine because the area is closed while the panel is still open...
So after reading some discussions on the topic on these pages, I thought of moving the closing of the area into a function and calling it with a timer, in the hope that it will be executed immediately after closing the panel, thus avoiding the errors mentioned above.
Well, timer and area closing work, but after clicking the panel button, the popup stays open for a few seconds and then Blender crashes.
Here is the relevant code:

```py
    def close_area( w, s, a):
        context = bpy.context
        if hasattr(context, "temp_override"):   # override in Blender >= 3.2
            with context.temp_override(windw=w, screen=s, area=a):
                bpy.ops.screen.area_close()
        else:   # legacy override (Blender < 3.2)
            override = {'window': w, 'screen': s, 'area': a}
            bpy.ops.screen.area_close(override)
    
    class VIEW3D_OT_close_area(bpy.types.Operator):
        bl_idname = "view3d.close_area"
        bl_label = "Close Area"
    
        def execute(self, context):
            bpy.app.timers.register(functools.partial(close_area, context.window, context.screen, context.area), first_interval=0.2)
            return {'FINISHED'}
```

I can't understand if there is some conceptual problem in following this path or if it is not the correct way.
Can you help me figure out what's wrong?
Or alternatively suggest me a better way to close a specific area from a popup panel?
Thank you!

Comment: Hello, maybe not related but you have a typo in your override arguments : `windw=w, screen=s, area=a`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not what caused the problem, but thanks @Gorgious so much for reporting it, I fixed it right away!